# Saving only difference in custom class matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, processing-efficiency, savechanges, memory-efficient

I have defined a class Results that is supposed the hold the results of a certain operation. I perform this operation 10.000 times and add the result to the result class.

Since this operation is slow, to prevent data loss, I save the temporary results every time (that is, I call save('tempResults.mat', 'obj') inside a method in my class)

The issue is that I write from scratch the whole class every time. But by the 5000th time, the class is already ~ 1 Gb big. 
It is unusable to write 1 Gb of data 10.000 times, especially when only something small changes in in the class.

How do I solve this? Apparently the save function in matlab doesn't support this. I can also write a custom save function for my class (saving separately some matrix and vectors and then loading it again when it's time) but even for array or matrices the save function in matlab doesn't support appending new rows. So how to implement this?

Comment: Maybe you can cache the old results within the object and only write out to disk every `N` times that it's modified? Otherwise, you'll have to develop a custom function to look for properties that have changed and come up with your own way of tracking those changes. I'm envisioning a data structure similar to the JSON patch [spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902)

Comment: Also have you looked at potentially using a `matfile` object?

Comment: I test this problem with persistent variables ... simply save your variables in persistent variable and this prevent to paging in memory

Comment: @saeedmasoomi how does a persistent variable prevent data loss?

Comment: @suever I didn't actually, thanks for the input. I'll try to see if what I need it's possible with that. But I don't think it's such a weird requirement to be able to append a row to a matrix in a saved file, i thought it was going to be more straightforward :-)