# Using matfile results in huge files for no reason

Tags: matlab, memory, save

I need to be able to save only parts of variables, since it would take too much to save them from scratch every time. For this purpose I am using matifiles, as suggested here ([Saving only difference in custom class matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573751/saving-only-difference-in-custom-class-matlab))

So, in my custom class I defined a saveToFile function, that saves certain arrays from which later I will recover my class instance. I then use matfile to only change the difference in these arrays and not saving from the beginning the whole time.  And it works, as I can see that the size of the file increments with every column I append to my variables.

The problem is the ludicrous size of these files; after 5 iteration of my process, the size of the file is 20 Mb. If I load it into matlab with the load syntax, and then immediately resave it with save, it is only 1 Mb! And after 20 iteration, the file saved with matfile is 80 Mb, but if I load it into memory and immediately save it again with save, it's only 1.2 Mb!

So to be clear, there's a file called 'results.mat' that is 80Mb. If I write a = load('results.mat') and then save('results2.mat', 'a') it is only 1.2 Mb.

I am aware of the fact that there is some overhead for the use of matifles, but clearly it cannot be so huge. Also this overhead doesn't even appear to scale linearly! Can you guys tell me what is happening?

Comment: Not without some code. We have no way of knowing what you're doing otherwise.

Comment: Try using `-v7.0` rather than `-v7.3`

Comment: If this isn't actually a dupe (I'm pretty sure it is), let me know and I can reopen it.

Comment: @Suever so from what I gather from your answer matfiles are unusable. As soon as the file gets big enough for you to think about saving only parts of variables instead of the whole thing, the size increase will make it completely useless. Anyhow, I am saving a table array, but I can avoid it. The thing is that even when saving the whole variable "currentDate" (a datetime object) the size increases around 2 Mb. So just to replace (not even append) the currentDate variable, the file size grows by 2 Mb. Is that the same phenomenon in effect? If it is, who is using matfiles? They seem useless...

Comment: @Ant When saving the initial .mat file, use the `-v7.0` flag instead of the `-v7.3` flag and then it won't use an HDF5 file and you shouldn't have this issue.

Comment: @Suever but then I won't be able to only save parts of a variable, defeating the purpose of using matfiles

Comment: @Ant That's true. If you only have one variable that you're constantly over-writing, then there really is not going to be a benefit to a `matfile` except that you don't have to continuously type `save`, but rather just assign directly to it.